# Explicit probability for vertical 2D percolation

Tags: combinatorics

We have a $n \times n$ array of open and blocked sites. Some fluid falls from the top. We call a site "full" if it has fluid. Then the sites in the top row will be full as long as they are open. Unlike typical percolation, the fluid in this case can only move down. Thus, if the fluid goes down a column, it stops as soon as it reaches a blocked site. We say the array percolates if fluid flows to the bottom in some site.

Say we create an array of open and blocked sites such that a site is open with probability $p$ and otherwise blocked. What is the probability that an $n \times n$ array percolates?

What I've tried so far:

We can instead find the probability that the array does not percolate and use complementary probability. If an array does not percolate, that means every column has at least one blocked site. I'm not sure how I can calculate the probability of that, however.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt: The probability that a single column has at least one blocked site is 1-P(the column has no blocked site) = $1−p^n$ The probability of n columns each having at least one blocked site is then $(1−p^n)^n$. So your answer is $1−(1−p^n)^n$

[All the cell / column probabilities multiply because we assume their occupancies are independent of each other.]

PS: If you assume the first row is full of fluid, the answer would be $1−(1−p^{n-1})^n$

Comment: $p$ is the probability that the site is open so it would be $1 - p^n$ for the first thing and so forth, but I get your idea. I think this works - thanks

Comment: @Soke: Oh, of course. I'll edit it.